# How to do PUT and DELETE with Zend_Http_Client

Tags: zend-http-client

The Zend_Http_Client docs are confusing and hard to understand. Currently I am using the following code to GET information from the Challonge API:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client("https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/$bracket.json");
$client->setParameterGet(array(
    'api_key' => $apikey,
    'include_participants' => 1,
));
$feed = $client->request()->getBody();
```

Very simple, three lines. Now this is a GET. How would I do the same exact thing as a PUT? Passing parameters and everything. What about a DELETE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do

```
$client->request('POST')
```

or

```
$client->request('DELETE')
```

Comment: Ah... so its as simple as adding a parameter inside of the request? And it defaults to GET, which is why I never needed it before?

What about `setParameterGet`? Would I replace that with `setParameterPut`? Or is there a different way to do it?

Comment: It would be setParameterPost for POST

Comment: The API says it has to be a PUT, not POST... are they interchangeable?

Comment: You have to set raw data. http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Http/Client/Zend_Http_Client.html#setRawData. It has only convenience methods for GET and POST

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I know this is not directly related to the question Json Axelrod asked, but I had a similar problem and could not find the solution anywhere online.

I was trying to do a PUT / DELETE request with Magentos `Varien_Http_Client`

> `class Varien_Http_Client extends Zend_Http_Client`

So I thought the same would apply that was written in this topic [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818014/how-to-set-the-content-type-with-zend-http-client-on-put). However no matter what I tried I could not get PUT nor DELETE requests to work.

**Really simple solution in that case:** Use Zend_Http_Client instead of Varien_Http_Client.
It seems that Magentos Http Client class is adding some extra "convenient" methods for preparing the body that won't allow PUT nor DELETE requests.

Comment: @MrSnoozies gotta love those "features". this one just made me lose two hours

Comment: @GabrielQueirozSilva Same here, except lost quite a log more hours. What is the point of making own shitty wrapper around a perfectly good framework?